# Cannot get tinyMCE textarea to validate in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, tinymce

I have three partial views within a view that are toggled via radiobutton selection. Each partial view has it's own submit input and two of the partial views contain a tinyMCE textarea. When I only had one partial that contained a tinyMCE textarea, I was able to get that textarea to validate using .triggerSave(), but now that I have added the second tinyMCE textarea, I can't get either of the tinyMCE textareas to pass validation.

I tried many of the solutions found on similar questions here on SO, but I have not been successful in getting these textareas to pass validation.

Here is the tinyMCE pertinent code on the first partial:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    tinyMCE.init({
        mode: "specific_textareas",
        editor_selector: "mceEditorForAddRow",
        theme: "simple",
        width: "500",
        height: "300"
    });
});
```

```
 @using(Html.BeginForm("_AddSchemaRow","Database_Schema")
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#CreateRow").click(function () {
        tinyMCE.triggerSave();
    });
</script>
<table>
....
....
            <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SchemaElement)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.SchemaElement, new { @class = "mceEditorForAddRow" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SchemaElement)
            </td>
        </tr>
....
....
</table>
<p>
        <input id="CreateRow" type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
}
```

Here is the contoller's action for this first partial:

```
        public ActionResult _AddSchemaRow(int id)
    {
        SchemaRow schemaRow = new SchemaRow();
        schemaRow.DatabaseSchemaID = id;
        schemaRow.SchemaIndex = DatabaseSchema.GetSchemaHeadersByDatabaseSchemaID(id).Count() + 1;
        return PartialView(schemaRow);
    }
```

Here is the controller's POST action for this first partial:

```
        [HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult _AddSchemaRow(SchemaRow schemaRow)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            DatabaseSchemaViewModel vm = new DatabaseSchemaViewModel(DatabaseSchema.GetDatabaseSchemaByID(schemaRow.DatabaseSchemaID));
            vm.SchemaRowsAndHeaders = DatabaseSchemaViewModel.GetSchemaRowsAndHeadersBySchemaID(schemaRow.DatabaseSchemaID);
            if (SchemaRow.Create_SchemaRow(schemaRow))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { id = schemaRow.DatabaseSchemaID });
            }
            else
                return PartialView(schemaRow);
        }
        else
            return PartialView(schemaRow);
    }
```

The second partial is set up just like the first partial above, except contains a "SchemaHeader" rather than a "SchemaRow" in all applicable fields including the submit input id being "CreateSchemaHeader". I think example code should provide enough description of my problem. I can add the other partial's code if needed. Thanks in advance for any help in finding a solution.

Comment: Has mceEditorForAddRow been deprecated?  It's not coming up for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to finally figure it out. The solution was to add click function after the input that the input that causes the postback.

Example:

```
<p>
    <input id="CreateRow" type="submit" value="Create" />
</p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#CreateRow").click(function () {
            tinyMCE.triggerSave();
        });
    </script>
```